# How to construct a tuple with only one element in standard ML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

In standard ML (Standard ML of New Jersey), we use following syntax to construct tuple

```
val x = (1, 2);
val u = ();
```

However we can not construct tuple with only one element

```
val x = (1); (* normal int *)
val y = (1,); (* python syntax, not valid in SML *)
```

On the other hand, one element tuple and element itself seems have same type signature.

Can we distinct `'a` and a tuple with only one element of type `'a` in SML?
If so, how can we construct a one element tuple and what's type signature of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we distinct `'a` and a tuple with only one element of type `'a` in SML?

Yes, you can.

Unlike Python, there isn't any special `(1,)` syntax. But since tuples are equivalent to records with numbered fields, you can create a record with exactly one field named `1` and access it using the `#1` macro for getting the first value of a tuple:

```
- val foo = { 1 = 42 };
val foo = {1=42} : {1:int}

- #1 foo;
val it = 42 : int
```

You can see that this is actually a 1-tuple by trying to annotate a regular 2-tuple as a record:

```
- (3.14, "Hello") : { 1 : real, 2 : string };
val it = (3.14,"Hello") : real * string
```

> what's type signature of it?

The type would be `{ 1 : 'a }`. You can preserve the type parameter like this:

```
type 'a one = { 1 : 'a };
```

You could get something similar using a `datatype`:

```
datatype 'a one = One of 'a
fun fromOne (One x) = x
```

I think those would use the same amount of memory.